# Not Getting Resposne when making Request using volley

Tags: java, android, xmlhttprequest, android-volley

I'm trying to  make a request to server using volley and check the returned value contains specific value or not. It works when I use separate class and call from Mainactivity using intent in onCreate.

But I would like to make a call manually when button is clicked from fragment but when button is clicked nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
 mCeload = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.Update);
    mCeload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String url = "https://cmprc.edu.np/batch/update.json";
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    if(response != null ) {
                        boolean resp = response.contains("1");

                        if (!resp) {

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Contacts are Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Updates Availaible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    volleyError.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You clicked the Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

I"m positive that button is clicked since I"m getting last toast message but before that nothing happens and I"m not getting any Toast of whether response was positive or negative.

Also How do  i get the response as string and store in local database such that I could compare the saved value with new one when user check for updates and if both value matches then show Toast of no updates available and if not then show updates available.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add your request on the RequestQueue like this way:

```
final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity);
                String url = "https://cmprc.edu.np/batch/update.json";
                    // Initialize a new StringRequest
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
                            Request.Method.GET,
                            url,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                     if(response != null ) {
                        boolean resp = response.contains("1");

                        if (!resp) {

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Contacts are Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Updates 
                            Availaible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } } 

                            },
                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void 
                                onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                volleyError.printStackTrace();                               
                                }
                            }
                    );

                    // Add StringRequest to the RequestQueue
                    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: It works.Thanks. How do I get the response inside  boolean resp = response.contains("1"); in string?